# How can I retrieve only upvoted Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the gem called 'acts_as_votable' (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)
Now, I'm trying to fetch particular records of Codes.

1. Code: belongs_to User & Community
2. Community: has_many Codes
3. User: has_many Codes

   ```
   #fetching all the communities that current_user voted up.
   @communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)

   #Now I'm trying to retrieve all users who belongs to any of '@communities'
   @users = @communities.???????(User)
   @codes = users.codes
   ```

How can I code to retrieve codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the wished entries from the table users when you have sampled all code from the wished communities. Try:

```
@codes  = []
@communities.each do |community|
  @codes.concat(community.codes)
end
User.where(code: @codes).order(:active_at)
```

See also:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you add an order by 'user.active_at' ??